# Download from a http location using apache camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to download a file from an http location to my local system using apache camel. When I gave the below code

```
    from("http://url/filename.xml")                         
    .to("file://C:location")
```

it has worked for ftp but not working when the url is "http".  That is, it is not downloading the file from the http location to the local address provided in the "to()".

Comment: explain not working

Comment: Not working means, it is not downloading the file,
I just want to know the code for downloading a file from an http location to the local using apache camel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
 from("direct:abc")
            .setHeader("Accept", simple("application/xml"))//Change it according to the file content
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
            .to("http://url/filename.xml")
            .to("file:///tmp/?fileName=yourFileName.xml");
```

You cannot use `from("Some url")`. Above route is triggered whenever there is a message on direct:abc endpoint. You can change the yourFileName.xml  to whatever filename you want it to be stored as.

Instead of a trigger from route, you can as well use a timer or any other means of self triggering.

The reason you cannot consume from a rest enpoint like this

```
from("http://url/filename.xml")
```

is you cannot consume from http endpoint. So there needs to be a trigger. Infact the exception message is pretty clear when you do like this. It says

```
org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[http://url/filename.xml]] -> [To[... because of Cannot consume from http endpoint
```

Comment: How to add a timer so that the file will be downloaded at certain intervals ?

Comment: instead of `from("direct:abc")` just add this line `from("timer:foo?fixedRate=true&period=5000")`

Comment: How can I download the file once in a month or weekly ? I would like to know the type of intervals I could set.
Any document for reference would be appreciated.

Comment: check this for timer documentation. http://camel.apache.org/timer.html. If you want sophisticated trigger, then you should check quartz component, where you can specify trigger using cron expressions. http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html

Answer (score 0):

the http component cannot be used as a consumer ie. you cannot have a route as from("http://...")

you need to use a consumer component that will start the route.
You could try something like this

```
from("timer:foo?fixedRate=true&period=5000")
.to("http://url/filename.xml")                         
.to("file://C:location")
```

Comment: Thanks, but the file downloaded is renamed to some other name. Even if the url is specified as 

        .to("url/?filename=filename.xml")

it is downloading with another filename and other format type.